# Firebase getUid() function only returns NULL

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

PostListFragment is extended by other fragments in my app.  I need the uid of the current user, but it always returns null.  When I try to run my app, I always get the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cleeg.squad, PID: 8524
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
     at com.example.cleeg.squad.fragments.PostListFragment.getUid(PostListFragment.java:162)
     at com.example.cleeg.squad.fragments.MyPostsFragment.getQuery(MyPostsFragment.java:19)
     at com.example.cleeg.squad.fragments.PostListFragment.onActivityCreated(PostListFragment.java:76)
```

I've tried to find out why this is online, but I just get more confused and I don't really know how to fix it.
The function getUid() is at the bottom of the code.

```
public abstract class PostListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "PostListFragment";

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
private LinearLayoutManager mManager;

public PostListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_posts, container, false);

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabaseReference);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
            PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Set click listener for the whole post view
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Launch PostDetailActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabaseReference.child("posts").child(postRef.getKey());
                    DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabaseReference.child("user-posts").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                    onStarClicked(userPostRef);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}

public String getUid() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}

public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);
```

}

Comment: The User from FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ist null, maybe there is no user signed in?

Comment: ahhh...I haven't signed in yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is because of no user is linked, i.e., getCurrentUser() is null. Please make user you have the user before fetching the userid.

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        mUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
} else {
        //login or register screen
}
```

Comment: would the above code be within the getUid() function?

Comment: yes, you can add it in the guid(). return mUserID in case of user exist or else handle the login/register.once the user is either signup or login, you can able to get the userID.

Comment: Launch either as activity or fragment. for ex. startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is authenticated and now you can access uesr's properties as followings
    mUserID = user.getUid();
} else {
    // User is authenticated. So, let's try to re-authenticate
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

    // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
    user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
        }
    });
}
```

You can get details on it in this firebase document:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)